# React problem with rendering current content of Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-storage, es6-promise

I'm working on form and I have problem with file input. I'm adding files onChange in input to firebase storage (it works fine) and I want to instantly render it to check if correct files was attached. Problem is that when I'm adding file it will be displayed after reloading the page or some change i code (forced to rerender component).

```
const FileInput = () => {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState(null)
    const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState()
    const inputRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        const imageListRef = ref(storage, 'images')
        const uploadedFilesFunction = async () => {
            const response = await listAll(imageListRef)
            const data = await Promise.all(response.items.map(item => item.name))
            setUploadedFiles(data)
        }
        uploadedFilesFunction()
    }, [])

    const addFiles = event => {
        const arrayFiles = Array.from(event.target.files)
        if (files == null) {
            setFiles(arrayFiles)
        } else {
            setFiles(prev => {
                return [...prev, ...arrayFiles]
            })
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (files != null) {
            files.forEach(file => {
                const fileRef = ref(storage, `images/${file.name}`)
                uploadBytes(fileRef, file).then(() => {})
            })
        } else {
            return
        }
    }, [files])

    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            <div className={classes.dragdrop} onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>
                <p className={classes.header}>
                    <span>Choose files</span>
                </p>
                <input type="file" hidden multiple onChange={addFiles} ref={inputRef} />
            </div>

            {uploadedFiles && <UploadedFiles uploadFiles={uploadedFiles} />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default FileInput
```

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const UploadedFiles = props => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.uploadFiles.map((file, idx) => (
                <li key={idx}>
                    <p>{file}</p>
                    <span>
                        {<FontAwesomeIcon id={idx} icon={faXmark} />}
                    </span>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default UploadedFiles
```

Firstly I tried use useRouterLoaderData from react-router-dom to load content from Firebase storage before rendering FileInput but InputFile is deeply nested to route page and change in InputFile doesn't trigger rerender root component so loader is not triggered. Now I try using useEffect triggered but I think there is some problem with Promise.